# I keep getting this error when i create a simple button in kotlin -> Error inflating class Button

Tags: android, kotlin, button, runtimeexception

This is the error, its just a simple button

```
2022-12-29 21:22:20.332 3888-3888/com.example.clapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.clapp, PID: 3888
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.clapp/com.example.clapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.clapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.clapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
```

It gives me error in last line for some reason

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral20"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.446" />
```

Comment: Have you messed with the theme at all? Is your Activity a subclass of AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**Main Activity Source**

[image]

**activity_main XML**

[image]

**Enable ViewBinding from gradle**

[image]